# Combine Spring HTTP Basic Authentication and Access Token

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

How to combine Spring HTTP Basic Authentication and Access Token for both would work simultaneously? In my case only configuration with Order(1) does works.

I want that all */api**/* would be accessed only for users with token and */web**/* would be accessed only for login users.

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/web/**", "/gopr").authenticated().and().authorizeRequests()
.and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/gopr", true).permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(2)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit", "client_credentials")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .secret("password")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600);
        // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/web/**", "/login", "/index", "/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
            /* antMatchers("/web/**", "/gopr").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated(); */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Always use 'requestMatchers()' when creating security filters. This way when multiple filter chains are created, only the first filter chain will not be used.

Modify both your WebSecurityConfig.java as :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    @Order(1)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/web/**", "/gopr")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/web/**", "/gopr").authenticated().
                .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/gopr", true).permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
        }
      ...
    }
```

and your ResourceServer inner class as :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        ...
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        }


    }
```

Reference : https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/issues/11